# "Application/vnd.api+json" throws "Unsupported Media Type"

Tags: rest, rest-assured, rest-assured-jsonpath

I am automating an API for a POST call using Rest Assured and for Content-Type and ACCEPT header I have to use "**application/vnd.api+json**". But every time I use "application/vnd.api+json" I get 415 status code.
Although the same POST call using Postman works perfectly fine.

Here is my sample code :

```
    ApiUtils.setBaseURI("xxxxx"); 
            ApiUtils.setBasePath("/orders"); 
            RequestSpecification request = RestAssured.given().auth().oauth2(BaseClass.token);
            request.header("ACCEPT", "application/vnd.api+json");
            request.header("Content-Type", "application/vnd.api+json");
            request.body(JsonCreator.createJson());
            Response response = request.post();
```

Below is the response received

```
Request method: POST
Request URI:    https://xxxxxx/orders

Headers:        ACCEPT=application/vnd.api+json
                Content-Type=application/vnd.api+json; charset=ISO-8859-1
Cookies:        <none>
Multiparts:     <none>
Body:
{
    "data": {
        "type": "orders",
        "attributes": {
            "external_id": "2020-04-04-172",
            "order_items": [
                {
                    "menu_item_id": "5d29ae25805aaf0009095410",
                    "variation_id": "5d29ae25805aaf0009095418",
                    "quantity": 1,
                    "note": "some note"
                }
            ],
            "revenue_center_id": "5d7b44021a2976000938da62",
            "order_type_id": "5d27329790a5ba0009386a75",
            "guests": [
                {
                    "first_name": "xx",
                    "last_name": "xx",
                    "email": "xx@gp.com",
                    "phone": "5551234567"
                }
            ],
            "tip_amount": "1.00"
        }
    }
}

{"errors":[{"status":415,"code":415,"title":"Content-Type must be JSON API-compliant"}],"jsonapi":{"version":"1.0"}}
```

I have tried changing the Content-Type to application/json as suggested by other posts/comment but that seems to be incorrect for my resource.

Currently, I am using Rest Assured v4.3.0 and json-path v4.3.0.
Also, to frame the request body I am using com.google.gson.JsonObject library.

Comment: Add a log().all() after give() and then() and post the output here

Comment: @WilfredClement I have updated my response body

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the logs you can see "**charset=ISO-8859-1**" being sent which is added automatically by Rest Assured, the .config() disables that and the charset is not sent

Try the below

```
ApiUtils.setBaseURI("orders");
ApiUtils.setBasePath("/orders");
RequestSpecification request = RestAssured.given().auth().oauth2(BaseClass.token).header("Content-Type", "application/vnd.api+json").header("Accept", "application/vnd.api+json").config(RestAssured.config().encoderConfig(encoderConfig().appendDefaultContentCharsetToContentTypeIfUndefined(false))).log().all();
request.body(JsonCreator.createJson());
Response response = request.post();
```

This also needs a static import

> import static io.restassured.config.EncoderConfig.encoderConfig;

https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured/wiki/Usage#avoid-adding-the-charset-to-content-type-header-automatically

Comment: Same error: Status Code- 406
{"errors":[{"status":406,"code":406,"title":"Accept header must be JSON API-compliant"}],"jsonapi":{"version":"1.0"}}

Comment: Tried Code:----  ApiUtils.setBaseURI("orders"); 
  ApiUtils.setBasePath("/orders"); 
  RequestSpecification request =  RestAssured.given().header("Content-Type","application/vnd.api+json")
    .config(RestAssured.config().encoderConfig(encoderConfig().appendDefaultContentCharsetToContentTypeIfUndefined(false)))
    .log().all();
  request.body(JsonCreator.createJson());
  Response response = request.post();

Comment: I seems to be a different error and not the same error, you were getting 415 earlier and now I see 406. Also, in the above why do I not see the oauth and accept header being sent ? Nevertheless - I have updated my answer by including the oauth and accept header in the same format as that you have put up in the question, try this and let me know

Comment: The only change in the original request of yours should be the .config method along with the static import and the remaining should be as such

Comment: Yes Indeed. I missed to add headers which caused this error... your suggested changes worked well...can you please help me understand what was causing the initial error?

Comment: I have updated by answer with an explanation, please check now