# Getting error stating "Content-Type must be 'application/json' or 'application/octet-stream'" even though specified in request header

Tags: rest-assured

Issue: I have written a Maven project using Java8 programming language with Rest-Assured for Restful API testing with the help of Serenity BDD Cucumber.

```
Request method: POST
Request URI:    https://merchantapi.taal.com/mapi/tx
Proxy:          <none>
Request params: <none>
Query params:   <none>
Form params:    <none>
Path params:    <none>
Headers:        Accept=*/*
                Content-Type=application/json; charset=UTF-8
Cookies:        <none>
Multiparts:     <none>
Body:
{
    "rawtx": ""
}

Response:

HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST,OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Sun, 12 Apr 2020 14:20:28 GMT
Content-Length: 105
Content-Type: application/json

{
    "status": 400,
    "code": 21,
    "error": "Content-Type must be 'application/json' or 'application/octet-stream'"
}
```

Attached the screenshot of PostMan for reference where it works fine.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9kEVz.png)
Please let me know if need any more information.

Comment: The error seems to be because of the charset that is being along with "application/json", 
You will have to set the below appendDefaultContentCharsetToContentTypeIfUndefined(false) in the code, Check the answer in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61024946/application-vnd-apijson-throws-unsupported-media-type/) link for further details

Comment: Awesome @WilfredClement added as below and worked, thank you :)              restRequest = SerenityRest.given()
                .config(RestAssuredConfig.config().encoderConfig(EncoderConfig.encoderConfig()
                        .appendDefaultContentCharsetToContentTypeIfUndefined(false)))
                .filter(new OverrideContentTypeFilter())
                .log().all().baseUri(endPoint);