# RestAssured : annot determine how to serialize content-type application/x-www-form-urlencoded. How to create request with key/value structure?

Tags: java, rest-assured, rest-assured-jsonpath

I have the following `postman` collection :

```json
{
    "info": {
        "_postman_id": "b172f7d9-xxxxxxx",
        "name": "protection",
        "schema": "https://schema.getpostman.com/json/collection/v2.1.0/collection.json"
    },
    "item": [
        {
            "name": "protection-example_IP ONLY",
            "request": {
                "method": "POST",
                "header": [
                    {
                        "key": "Content-Type",
                        "value": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
                    }
                ],
                "body": {
                    "mode": "urlencoded",
                    "urlencoded": [
                        {
                            "key": "ApiKey",
                            "value": "62fdc812-be58-xxxxx",
                            "type": "text"
                        },
                        {
                            "key": "TagId",
                            "value": "1111",
                            "type": "text"
                        },
                        {
                            "key": "ClientIP",
                            "value": "200.55.111.111",
                            "type": "text"
                        },
                        {
                            "key": "RequestURL",
                            "value": "http://awesomeSite.com",
                            "type": "text"
                        },
                        {
                            "key": "ResourceType",
                            "value": "text/html",
                            "type": "text"
                        },
                        {
                            "key": "Method",
                            "value": "GET",
                            "type": "text"
                        },
                        {
                            "key": "Host",
                            "value": "awesomeSite.com",
                            "type": "text"
                        },
                        {
                            "key": "UserAgent",
                            "value": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Safari/537.36",
                            "type": "text"
                        },
                        {
                            "key": "Accept",
                            "value": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9",
                            "type": "text"
                        },
                        {
                            "key": "AcceptLanguage",
                            "value": "en-IL,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8,my;q=0.7",
                            "type": "text"
                        },
                        {
                            "key": "AcceptEncoding",
                            "value": "gzip, deflate, br",
                            "type": "text"
                        },
                        {
                            "key": "HeaderNames",
                            "value": "Host,User-Agent,Accept,Accept-Langauge,Accept-Encoding,Cookie",
                            "type": "text"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "url": {
                    "raw": "https://other.awesome.com/test-api",
                    "protocol": "https",
                    "host": [
                        "other",
                        "awesome",
                        "com"
                    ],
                    "path": [
                        "test-api"
                    ]
                }
            },
            "response": []
        },
    //.........
```

I need to create the same request using `rest-assured` framework,

I tried to create a map with keys/value and put it to the body:

```java
 Map<String,String> keys = new HashMap<String, String>(){{
            put("ApiKey", "62fdc812-be58-xxxxxx");
            put("TagId", "1111");
            //...
 }};

RestAssured.given()
                .contentType("application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
                .body(keys)
                .when().post("https://other.awesome.com/test-api")
                .then()
                .statusCode(200);
```

But got the error :

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot serialize because cannot determine how to serialize content-type application/x-www-form-urlencoded.

In the case when I use `formParams` instead `body`:

```java
RestAssured.given()
                .log().all()
                .formParams(keys)
                .when().post("https://other.awesome.com/test-api")
                .then()
                .statusCode(200);
```

I get the following error:

> ```
> Expected status code <200> doesn't match actual status code <415>
> ```

```json
HTTP/1.1 415 Unsupported Media Type
Content-Length: 149
Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'none'
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Date: Tue, 05 Jan 2021 09:50:12 GMT
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff

<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>Error</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <pre>Unsupported Media Type</pre>
  </body>
</html>
```

**How to correctly build request with Rest Assured for this pattern ?**

---

- Additional info:

In the `PostMan` request contains `key/value` map in the `body`. Tab `Params` is empty. But In the code, in the second case I haven't any data in the `body` section:

- Postman:

[image]

- Code logs:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are nearly there,

**Map :**

```
Map<String, String> keys = new HashMap<String, String>() {
            {
                put("ApiKey", "62fdc812-be58-xxxxxx");
                put("TagId", "1111");
            }
        };
```

**Rest Assured Code :**

```
RestAssured.given().formParams(keys).when().post("https://other.awesome.com/test-api").then()
                .statusCode(200);
```

Rest Assured sets the `Content-Type` as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` automatically when you use the `formParams()`

**Update :**

I'm guessing you are getting `Unsupported Media Type` because Rest Assured sets a default charset in the request for `Content-Type`

[image]

Try with the below code

```
RestAssured.given().log().all()
                .config(RestAssured.config()
                        .encoderConfig(encoderConfig().appendDefaultContentCharsetToContentTypeIfUndefined(false)))
                .formParams(keys).when().post("https://other.awesome.com/test-api").then().statusCode(200);
```

You need to import encoderConfig as static

```
import static io.restassured.config.EncoderConfig.encoderConfig;
```

Check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61031436/3190953) for more information on the encoderConfig

If you still have issues, From POSTMAN follow the below steps

[image]

Add a `.log().all()` after `given()` in your Rest Assured code and compare the results

Comment: Thanks. But do not work also. Now I got error 415: "Unsupported Media Type - Status Codes"

Comment: 403 is due to authorization, please check your `apiKey` value and other details

Comment: As it turned out - the service has protection settings and forbids access for 10 minutes if a bad request was sending. So your update works well. Great thanks!